# Bandwidth required for an arbitrary digital signal

Tags: digital-logic

For a project at work, I need to figure out the bandwidth requirements for a digital signal so I can spec components.

My first thought was to look at the Fourier Series for a pulse wave. I got so far as determining that the Fourier Series for a pulse wave or rectangular wave was something with the sin(x)/x function in it. I didn’t actually compute the Fourier Series myself I just found that information online – before I could attempt anything like that I found this rule that I had forgotten about. That the spectral content of a digital signal is related to the rise time. When I tried to use that "rule of thumb" for this project I found myself with a few questions.

Why is it seemingly universally recommended that you use the rise time to find the spectral content of a digital signal and not the Fourier Series representation? Seems that they would be equivalent, is it just that using the rise time is "easier"?

I can find the rise time for a signal easily with an oscilloscope, however, once I run that signal though anything, a longer cable, a coupler, an amplifier, a power splitter, an IC, won't the component affect the rise time of the signal? How do I know the bandwidth requirements of the signal after its gone through some component or device? How am I supposed to know the bandwidth requirement at any point along the signal’s path without directly measuring it after each component or device?

More Details: I have a 1.28 MHz clock signal, a pulse wave, that is already synthesized. It runs through a ~100' cable to a rack of electronics. I need to design a chassis that takes the signal, buffers it and distributes it, providing a copy of the signal for use at that area, and two more copies of it, to be sent through similar ~100' cables to be used elsewhere.

Comment: You need to discuss the rack(s) of equipment and how that signal is used -- at the source where it is generated (and possibly used there), at your local rack where it is used and you need to generate a repeater for elsewhere, and "elsewhere" it also gets used. I kind of gather it doesn't matter too much, as you don't have a solution right now and are getting by using other means right now. So this might be very easy. Rise time is often used for loading questions, as outputs are driving capacitive loads. But it does tell you something about the spectral content above the frequency of interest.

Comment: @jonk what? I don't understand

Comment: That's fine. Let's chalk it up to my confusion, then.

Comment: You need a peak frequency somewhat higher than your bits per second data rate (2x will usually suffice).  Rise/fall time isn't important so long as you can reconstruct the pulses before feeding into any digital logic.

Answer (score 8):

> Why is it seemingly universally recommended that you use the rise time to find the spectral content of a digital signal and not the Fourier Series representation?

Because if you consider waveforms with different rise and fall times, they'll have different Fourier series (or Fourier transform) representations.

The width of the spectrum in the frequency domain will drop as the rise and fall times increase.

> I can find the rise time for a signal easily with an oscilloscope, however, once I run that signal though anything, a longer cable, a coupler, an amplifier, a power splitter, an IC, won't the component affect the rise time of the signal?

It depends on whether you've chosen those components with enough bandwidth to support the rise time you want to have for your signal.

> How do I know the bandwidth requirements of the signal after its gone through some component or device? How am I supposed to know the bandwidth requirement at any point along the signal’s path without directly measuring it after each component or device?

Practically, it doesn't matter what the rise and fall time are at the signal source. More important is what rise and fall time you need to have for your receiver to work reliably. Then design your signal path with enough bandwidth to be sure that the rise and fall times don't get too slow before the signal gets to the receiver.

Answer (score 5):

Frequency is not important, rise time is.

Ideal square waves have infinite bandwidth. Real-world square waves like your clock signal has some limited rate at which the signal changes (called slew rate), and thus the signal will have non-zero rise/fall times, so it won't have infinite bandwidth.

Imagine you have two square wave signals one at 1 Hz frequency, and other at 1 MHz frequency, and they have identical sharp 10 nanosecond edges, so that if you zoom in with an oscilloscope to see a single edge, you won't be able to tell if you are looking at a 1 Hz or 1 MHz signal (except from the screen update rate, of course, but that's irrelevant).

Both of these signals require equal bandwidth for the identical 10ns edges to pass a transmission medium such as cable to the receiver. So the whole system must support enough bandwidth to pass 10ns edges without distortion, no matter what the signal frequency is.

That 10ns rise time is 1% of the 1us period of the 1 MHz signal, so the transition is quite fast compared to the signal period, the "eye diagram" is like a rectangle. It's even more obvious rectangle on the 1 Hz signal.

As you may not need such high rise times which require high bandwidth, you can slow down the edges to say 100ns rise time, that's 10% of the 1us for the 1 MHz signal. So the eye diagram starts to look more hexagonal. If your receiver can handle 100ns rise times just fine, you don't need higher bandwidth from the transmitter and the signal path, and you can even limit the slew rate at the transmitter already. Again the edges of 1 Hz and 1 MHz square waves look identical, but the signal bandwidth is reduced to a level that is enough for the system to still work.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the data_eye you need. A 1_tau setting to 63 %, is only 13% above the midpoint threshold typically used. So you need about 2_tau settling.

You ask why we don't use the Fourier modeling?

Because signals happen in time, not in frequency.

And a small bit of frequency peaking near the fundamental, will make up for lots of higher frequency attenuation.

================================================

Find the slowest module of your system. Determine its bandwidth, and determine its time_constant.

Use that time_constant as I explained.

When you have multiple identical slow modules, then increase the computed time_constant by squareroot of the # of modules.

Comment: data_eye? 1_tau? 2_tau? Settling? It should like your saying the frequency isn't important, that's literally what I'm asking about...

Answer (score 0):

Considering practicalities of your "project at work": 1.28 MHz is not that high a frequency to be worried about signal distortion when it is fed via a 100' cable or is amplified in commercial electronics units, provided pulse wave's duty cycle is not dangerously close to 0 or 100 per cent. Ordinary cabling inserts phase shift; for this reason, at a remote rack, you can use the received clock signals only for local syncing. So, why not generate 1.28 MHz clocks locally for each rack and not bother itself with transmitting a unique clock over cables? There is a number of off-the-shelf precision real time clock units outputting 1.28 MHz, 5.12 MHz, 10.24 MHz.

A few words about the theory you mention in your post. The **Fourier series** of the ideal square wave (rectangular pulses repeating with a frequency f) computed with **Fourier expansion** over time `T = 1/f` is proportional to `sin(2π∙f∙t) + (1/3)∙sin(3∙2π∙f∙t) + (1/5)∙sin(5∙2π∙f∙t) + ...` . This series sums up to a function of `t`, while `f` is a constant. On the other hand, the `sinc` function `sin(πf∙T)/(πf∙T)` is a **Fourier transform** for a **unit pulse** of duration `T`. The Fourier transform is a function of `f`, here time `T` is a constant. Do not take this explanation for pedantry; it makes a great difference how you name things when, for example, asking questions on SE.

A sketch of analysis for "a longer cable, a coupler, an amplifier, a power splitter, an IC" contribution into accumulated signal distortion.

For a cable, you compare the dominant frequencies' wavelengths of the signal propagating in the cable with the cable length and then decide, is it a **transmission line** or just a connector wires. At 1.28 MHz, the wavelength in a, say, RG-58 100' coax cable is `(light velocity) * (cable velocity factor) / frequency` = 3∙10^8 ∙ 0.66 / 1.28∙10^6 = 156 m. Therefore, a 100' cable is not a transmission line for a signal characterized by a dominant 1.28 MHz freq and only cable material's properties can contribute into **frequency dispersion**. RG-58 dielectric (polyethylene) is a good insulator and losses are only due to conductor resistance, 39_Ohm/km for RG-58. The DC resistance of a 100' cable segment is 0.013 Ohm; the conductor's contribution into losses is insignificant. 'A longer cable', if much longer than 156 m, is a transmission line for pulses shorter than 0.5/1.28 MHz = 0.39usec. The **impedance of transmission line** is `SQRT((R+jwL)/(G+jwC))` and at frequencies much higher than `R/L` = 57 KHz (for RG-58), impedance `Z_0 = SQRT(L/C)`; the impedance do not depend on frequency up to the cutoff frequency (750 MHz for RG-58) and the pulse propagates with constant shape (frequency dispersion is low). Again, signal rise times do not degrade, only signal power attenuates with distance.

"A coupler, a power splitter" are **passive microwave devices**. When used appropriately, these devices do not distort pulse shapes and have no effect on signal rise times. In circuit calculations, these devices are described by their **scattering parameters (s-parameters)**.

"An amplifier, an IC" components are predominantly less spacious when compared with wavelengths corresponding to operation frequencies. In a **linear signal approximation**, these components can be modeled by **two-port or multiport networks**. The network's **z-, y-, h-parameters** are used to calculate the response of the network to the signals applied to the ports. To account for frequency dependence, equations are written in the **Laplace domain (s-domain)**. The **Laplace transform** can be related to the Fourier transform, but these are not the same.

A signal processing chain for measuring instruments may include components that are not linear and even cannot be linearized for calculations. The **comparators** generate signals with short transition times from arbitrary analog signals. A **constant fraction discriminator** generate a digital signal when input signal reaches its local maxima. For devices of this sort, you look for output signal rise/fall times in the corresponding datasheets.

I highlighted the terms you may want to find and read about in literature.